# How to print a string in erb file including line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, erb

After getting an input from a user, I'm having a string like so:

```
str = "First line/nSecond line/nThird line"
```

When I'm trying to print it in my `erb` file like so:

```
<%= str %>
```

I'm getting only one line without any line's breaks ("First line Second line Third line")

**My question is:**

How to print a string in `erb` file **including** the line's breaks?

*(I guess i can replace every \n with `<br>` tag but I wonder if there's a better way of achieving that?!)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with `ruby-on-rails` I guess you want to output to a webpage. I would recommend this:

```
<%= simple_format(str) %>
```

Form the docs:

```
simple_format("Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break.")
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<pre>` tag. . . .. . . . . . .

Comment: Tx, but I upvoted the `simple_format()` answer. `<pre>` has issues (monospace font, won't easily wrap, etc.).